# Calendar not displaying when using AjaxControlToolkit-CalendarExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my aspx as below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager id="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateFerie" autopostback="True"/>
        <asp:Button runat="Server" ID="ibtnDateFerie" 
        CausesValidation="False" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ID="cbeDateFerie" runat="server" Enabled="True"
        TargetControlID="txtDateFerie" PopupButtonID="ibtnDateFerie" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have AjaxControlToolkit.dll and System.Web.Extensions.dll in my project.  However, when I click on the button, the calendar is not shown.  I have looked for an answer on the internet, and it seems I am not missing anything here.  Any idea where the problem may be?

Comment: Add `UseSubmitBehavior = false` on button named `ibtnDateFerie`.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:  This does not work

Comment: Check your developer console is it showing any kind of error?

Comment: Yes, I get this :ReferenceError: Type is not defined for Type.registerNamespace('AjaxControlToolkit');AjaxControlToolkit.BoxSide = function() {....                      and ReferenceError: Sys is not defined for Sys.Application.initialize(); and Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ToolkitScriptManager1', document.getElementById('form1'));

Comment: Add this `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` instead of ToolkitScriptManager .

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:  The above solution does not work either.

Comment: Look at this [Ajax Documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/configuringaspnetajax.aspx) it will help you in solving the problem.